# Promise return Promise status pending and promise value undefined in Odoo js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, odoo, point-of-sale

Hello I am trying to convert string html to image
using html2canvas library in my Odoo POS Module v8.
But, when I try to use this function

```
var receipt_data = html2canvas($(receipt)).then(function(canvas) {
            $('body').appendChild(canvas);
        });
```

it gives -

```
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
```

in receipt_data
I have included html2canvas.js in  my assets module.
Please help me...

Comment: What is `receipt`? What are you doing with `receipt_data` (which is a promise object)? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: reciept is string html by $(receipt) i have html element

Comment: I want canvas of string html

Comment: Never tried that. Always used dom element. Suggest you append string to dom and pass whatever container element you append it to as argument. Like `$('#container').append(receipt); html2Canvas($('#container')[0]).then...`